# Why are my new subviews superposing in my splitview?

Tags: cocoa, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to use to a NSSplitView in my Xamarin.Mac Application.
I need to add subviews programmatically for business reasons. It works fine, but there is a problem :

When I add a subview, it's added on the SplitView but on top of the precedent one : there's no separation between the subviews. They're superimposed. 
Here's how I do it :

```
        SplitView.AddSubview(View1);

        SplitView.AddSubview(View2);
```

My splitview is bound to the interface by an outlet type binding.
I guess I have to do something manually with the separators but the documentation is really lacking for both Xamarin and Cocoa and I can't find why.

Comment: `NSSplitView`: "A view that arranges two or more views in a linear stack running horizontally or vertically.". Do you want to add views to the splitview or to the views of the splitview? Are `addArrangedSubview:` and `insertArrangedSubview:atIndex:` what you're looking for?

Comment: this I was looking for, indeed. Thank you, sorry if this was trivial. If you put it in the answer I'll validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [NSSplitView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssplitview?language=objc)

> A view that arranges two or more views in a linear stack running horizontally or vertically.

Subviews added with `addSubview(_:)` aren't arranged. `NSSplitView` provides methods to add and remove arranged subviews:

```
func addArrangedSubview(_ view: NSView)
func insertArrangedSubview(_ view: NSView, at index: Int)
func removeArrangedSubview(_ view: NSView)
```